# How do I have get two different ouputs from one 'set /p' command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a batch program which has a password input request.  However I want to offer the user the option to either enter `?` for a password hint when this line of code `set /p PASSWORD1= Password:`  gets read by the parser.

What the user will see:

```
Welcome! If you know the password please enter it.  Otherwise, enter"?" to get a hint.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Password:
```

Where it says `Password:` , I want three variables, each will go to a label, correct password, incorrect password, or password hint, for `?`.

Here is the code I have so far that is related to this question:

```
echo.
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo   Welcome! If you know the password please enter it.  Otherwise, enter ? to get a hint.
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
set /p PASSWORD1= Password: 
if "PASSWORD1:~1,9%== TwilightLinkable
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (test1.txt) do (
    set TEXT=%%a
)
if %PASSWORD1%==%TEXT% goto rr
echo you are wrong!!!
pause
goto start
```

Thank you!

Comment: `"PASSWORD1:~1,9%` can never be `TwilightLinkable`, it is not possible for `"` to ever match `T`. Even with that rogue doublequote fixed or removed, it is not possible for the second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth, and tenth characters of their input to ever match any sixteen character string.

Comment: @Compo

Okay.  So what would be the proper code for it?  Will it be an if/else statement? I think that is what I need.

Comment: Well the first thing would be to learn how to use the `if`/`else` command. Open a Command Prompt window, type `if /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, to read its usage information. You can do the same with `set /?` to read some inofrmation of variable expansion for substrings. The command for a case insensitive match would be `If /I "%Var%" == "Str" …`, and for a case sensitive one, `If "%Var%" == "Str" …`. There should be no need to check a variable length, but if you wanted to restrict that length to a maximum of its first sixteen characters, you'd use `If "%Var:~0,16%" == "TwilightLinkable" …`

Comment: @KJ ,

I am having issues with the code for the password. When I either type in the correct password or ?, the program just closes on me.

Comment: @KJ here is what I have for the code

`set /p PASSWORD1=Password: 
if password1=? echo hint & goto hint
if password1=right goto steamid


for /f "Delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (

set TEXT=%%a

)

if %PASSWORD1%==%TEXT% goto steamid
goto incorrect`